# Exporting Plone Archetypes data in JSON

Tags: plone

I'd like to export Plone folder consisting of custom Archetypes content items in JSON.

What addons and tools there exist for this? Preferably one which automatically inspects schema and creates JSON structure based on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have successfully used [collective.jsonmigrator / collective.blueprint.jsonmigrator](https://github.com/collective/collective.jsonmigrator) for this purpose. It's meant to work with transmogrifier. I was even able to export json from a prehistoric Plone and import it into a Dexterity content type in Plone 4.1.

This kind of extreme migration is never easy, and if there's any customization at all, you'll probably need to do some source tuneups to make the pipeline work.